# how to get const value dynamically in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I get a constant's value dynamically similar to `constant()` in PHP?

Below, I would like to access `HELL_NO`, but I have `NO` in a variable. Why does this return `undefined`?

```js
const HELL_YES='warm';
const HELL_NO='cool';
var pick='NO';
console.log(window['HELL_'+pick]);
```

Comment: `const`s do not get assigned to `window`, only `var`s on the top level do. You could also define your own object instead, `const obj = { HELL_YES: 'warm', HELL_NO: 'cool' };` then use bracket notation on obj, `obj['Hell_' + pick]`

Comment: @flppv Of course I did, I wouldn't have VTC'd otherwise

Comment: I used window as an example, for it didn't work and I don't know how else to make it work, so I asked the question. Thank you

Comment: Well it's not the similar question, but I agree those answer contains answer to this question as well

Comment: I don't see how asking for the JavaScript equivalent to PHP's  `constant()` is similar to asking about the difference between `let` and `var`.

Comment: Since you have a list of options based on `pick`, you can avoid `eval` by using conditions, for example in a `switch` statement. `switch (pick) { case "YES": console.log(HELL_YES); break; case "NO": console.log("HELL_NO"); break; default: console.log("unexpected value", pick); }`

Comment: @JohnColeman There is no such thing as `constant()` in JS. The duplicates explain why `window['HELL_'+pick]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```js
const HELL_YES='warm';
const HELL_NO='cool';
var pick='NO';
console.log(eval("HELL_" + pick));
```

## EDIT

Because `eval` is `evil`, you should use an object instead:

```js
const obj = {
  HELL_YES: "warm",
  HELL_NO: "cool"
};

console.log(obj["HELL_" + "YES"]);
```

Comment: But as we all know, `eval` is evil! Use an object. And if you really need to protect it from changes, [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) it.

Comment: Yes @Jan-LucaKlees that is true.